# Endianness issue?

Tags: c, endianness

What will be the output of the following code?

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int a[4]={4096,2,3,4};
    char *p;
    p=a;
    printf("\n %d",(int)*(++p));
    return 0;
}

sizeof int = sizeof(void*) = 4 bytes
```

According to me the output should be 16 on a little endian machine and 0 on a big endian machine. Am I right?

Comment: it should be a compiler warning....:P

Comment: Why would you think those are going to be the output?

Comment: On this machine, what is the size of an int? (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/589575/c-size-of-int-long-etc) Did you mean to cast the input to printf to an int first? Using `(int)*(++p)` or `*((int *)++p)`?

Comment: Sizeof int is 4 bytes and sizeof void* is also 4 bytes

Comment: @sje397: technically I think it doesn't matter, at least with `CHAR_BIT==8`. A char varargs argument is promoted either to `int` or to `unsigned int` (6.5.2.2/7), and it's valid to read it as either, since the values "16" and "0" are representable in either (7.15.1.1/2). Might as well put it in, though...

Comment: what's the array for? it's only necessary if you meant `*((int *)++p)` as sje397 suggested

Answer (score 1, accepted):

4096 is `0x1000`, so (once you get it to compile) you'd expect 16 with a little-endian representation, and 0 with a big-endian representation unless `int` is 24 bits wide (that would give 16).

All this assuming `CHAR_BIT == 8`, and no funny-business with padding bits. The edit with `sizeof(int) == 4` also rules out the 24 bit `int` under those assumptions.

Answer (score 1):

4096 (hex 0x1000) will be represented in memory (assuming 8-bit bytes, which is quite common nowadays) as either:

```
[0x00, 0x00, 0x10, 0x00] (big-endian)
```

or

```
[0x00, 0x10, 0x00, 0x00] (little-endian)
```

Since you're printing it out using %d, which expects integers, but passing a dereferenced character pointer value (i.e., a `char`) and incrementing the pointer before dereferencing it, you will print either 0x00 or 0x10, which is 16 in decimal. You will probably need to add some cast to allow the `p = a` statement, since you're mixing types rather freely.

So yes, I think you're right.

Comment: You forgot middle-endian, `[0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x10]`

Comment: @Christoffer: You also forgot another middle-endian: `[0x10, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00]` :-)